# numpy 1.13 MaskedArrayFutureWarning: setting an item on a masked array which has a shared mask will not copy the mask

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I recently upgraded from numpy 1.11 to numpy 1.13 hoping to get rid of this masked array warning, but it's still there:

`MaskedArrayFutureWarning: setting an item on a masked array which has a shared mask will not copy the mask and also change the original mask array in the future.
Check the NumPy 1.11 release notes for more information.*`

Basically my code just changes some values in a masked array, and I'm not sure what this error even means.

I was hoping that the upgrade to numpy 1.13 would resolve this, but I think the error is on my end.

For clarity, I'm running numpy 1.13 despite the warning referencing 1.11:

> Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
>
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> import numpy as np
>
> np.**version**
>
> '1.13.0.dev0+Unknown'

Thanks for any help.
Cat

Comment: Have you studied this section: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#assigning-to-slices-views-of-maskedarray

Comment: Extended discussion on this warning: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7164.  I don't see evidence that it has been changed in newer releases.

Answer (score 11):

This shared mask business is a bit confusing.

The current behavior:

```
In [150]: x=np.ma.masked_greater(np.arange(8),5)
In [151]: x
Out[151]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [152]: y=x[3:6]          # a view
In [153]: y[0]=30           # modify the view
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: MaskedArrayFutureWarning: setting an item on a masked array which has a shared mask will not copy the mask and also change the original mask array in the future.
Check the NumPy 1.11 release notes for more information.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
```

`data` value change is shared with the source

```
In [154]: y
Out[154]: 
masked_array(data = [30 4 5],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [155]: x
Out[155]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 30 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

but a mask value change is not:

```
In [156]: y.mask[0]=True
In [157]: y
Out[157]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 4 5],
             mask = [ True False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [158]: x
Out[158]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 30 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Make a new view, and call the `unshare` method:

```
In [159]: y=x[3:6]
In [160]: y.unshare_mask()
Out[160]: 
masked_array(data = [30 4 5],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [161]: y[0]=31
In [162]: y
Out[162]: 
masked_array(data = [31 4 5],
             mask = [False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [163]: x
Out[163]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 31 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

This changes the `data`, without issuing the warning.

The future behavior, without the warning, can be produced with:

```
In [172]: x=np.ma.masked_greater(np.arange(8),5)
In [174]: y=x[3:6]
In [175]: y._sharedmask=False
In [176]: y[0]=30
In [177]: y.mask[0]=True
In [178]: y
Out[178]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 4 5],
             mask = [ True False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [179]: x
Out[179]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 -- 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False  True False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The new value and mask appear in both `y` and `x`.

The bottom line is - what should happen to the mask in `x` when you change values in `y` (data or mask)?  Change or not?

=================

Or a case where setting a data value in the view also changes the mask might be clearer:

```
In [199]: x=np.ma.masked_greater(np.arange(8),5)
In [200]: y=x[4:]
In [201]: y
Out[201]: 
masked_array(data = [4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [202]: y[-1]=0
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: MaskedArrayFutureWarning: setting an item on a masked array which has a shared mask will not copy the mask and also change the original mask array in the future.
Check the NumPy 1.11 release notes for more information.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
In [203]: y
Out[203]: 
masked_array(data = [4 5 -- 0],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [204]: x
Out[204]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The last `y` value was unmasked, but the corresponding `x` was not (I should have showed the change the `x.data`).  This is the current behavior that you are warned about.

But with the `future` behavior:

```
In [205]: y=x[4:]
In [206]: y._sharedmask=False
In [207]: y[-1]=0
In [208]: y
Out[208]: 
masked_array(data = [4 5 -- 0],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [209]: x
Out[209]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 -- 0],
             mask = [False False False False False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

`x` data and mask were changed along with `y`.

Comment: So helpful!  Really wish this answer had more visibility...  UPVOTE!

Comment: Great explanation. I was also left helpless with this warning - until now